# labeling data in a list

Tags: plotting, list-manipulation, labeling

I have the following list:

```
l={{1,2},{3,4},{5,6}}
```

I want to list plot above such that the first element {1,2} can be labeled "a", {3,4} labeled "b" and {5,6} to be labeled "c", I know I can label coordinates using,

```
ListPlot[Labeled[#, #] & /@ l]
```

for which I get,

[image]

But I want the label to be "a", "b" and "c"

Comment: `l = {{1, 2}, {3, 4}, {5, 6}};
labels = {"a", "b", "c"};
ListPlot[Labeled[l[[#]], labels[[#]]] & /@ Range[Length[l]]]`.

Comment: Thanks, if you post this as answer I can accept it :)

Comment: From the docs: `ListPlot[{{1, 2}, {3, 4}, {5, 6}} -> {"a", "b", "c"}, 
 LabelingFunction -> Above]`

Comment: LabelingFunction doesn't work for me

Comment: @user1066 has a better (simpler and direct) answer so that's the one you should select.  But your comment suggests you might have an older version of *Mathematica*.  It works fine on 11.3 Windows 10.  You should mention in your question which *Mathematica* version and operating system you have.

Comment: A slight improvement to @JimB's answer: `ListPlot[MapThread[Labeled,{l,labels}]]`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
list = {{1, 2}, {3, 4}, {5, 6}}; labels = {"a", "b", "c"};

ListPlot @ Thread @ Labeled[list, labels, Above]
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

```
list = {{1, 2}, {3, 4}, {5, 6}};

labels = {"a", "b", "c"};
```

`ListPlot` labels associations automatically

```
ListPlot @ AssociationThread[labels -> list]
```

[image]